# Inserting previously uploaded images into WYSIWYG editors

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm having a photo sharing feature on the site where users upload photos which are saved as nodes.

I want to be able to have them insert any of their previously uploaded photos into articles nodes and comments.

I haven't decided on TinyMCE vs. CKEditor plugins yet.

I want to do the same for videos they have uploaded.
 I haven't tried [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) yet but don't like the "windows explorer" like UI. Same with [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/demo)

Our old community site has such a feature for the TinyMCE editor but I'm not sure how they did that.

[image]

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I want my users be able to have them insert any of their previously uploaded photos into articles nodes and comments using a UI similar to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Media module, any image uploaded should be available in the WYSIWYG insert media library tab.

Answer (score 0):

IMCE works for me.  Yes, it has a Windows Explorer like interface but that said it works for files in your public directory.

I use the D8 Juicebox module and the separate PC Juicebox application.  Create galleries with pre-made images and thumbnails on the PC.  FTP the completed Gallery up to the public files area on D8.  If I want to re-use any image in another content type (say article) I just find it through IMCE and insert it.